Partial Derivative of Pullback of Differential form
I'm new to differential forms and the book I'm reading contains a part I don't understand.
It states the following:

Let $k\geq 1$ and assume that $D \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ and $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ are open subsets. Assume that $\phi:D \to U$ is a $C^2$ function and let $\omega$ be a $C^1$ differential $(k-1)$-form on $U$. Consider the function(s) $f_i:D \to \mathbb{R}$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$, given by :
\begin{align*}
f_i(y) = (\phi^* \omega)(y)(e_{\widehat{i}}) := \omega(\phi(y))(D_1\phi(y),\dots,\widehat{D_i\phi(y)},\dots,D_k\phi(y)).
\end{align*}
Then we have:
\begin{align*}
D_i f_i(y) = D\omega(\phi(y))(D_i\phi(y))(D_1\phi(y),\dots,\widehat{D_i\phi(y)},\dots,D_k\phi(y))+ \sum_{1 \leq j \leq k, \:j\neq i} \omega(\phi(y))(D_1\phi(y),\dots,\widehat{D_i\phi(y)},\dots,D_iD_j\phi(y),\dots,D_k\phi(y))
\end{align*}

I don't understand how to derive at this formula for the partial derivative. The book mentions a formula for the (total) derivative of a multi-linear map, but I don't see how that leads to this result.
Notation:

A hat on some symbol means that the symbol underneath is omitted. In particular we have $e_{\hat{i}} = (e_1,\dots,\widehat{e}_i,\dots,e_n)$
the $\phi^*$ is for the pullback
$D\omega$ is the derivative of the function $x \mapsto \omega(x)(v_1,\dots,v_{k})$ when $\omega$ is a $k$-form.

I hope that someone can help me, let me know if anything is unclear!

This strikes me as an extraordinarily clumsy approach. Of what result are you trying to understand the proof?

@TedShifrin This calculation is used to introduce exterior derivatives and then prove Stokes' theorem

It looks to me that the function(s) $f_i$ are the coefficients of the pulled back form $\phi^\omega,.$
The notation will become a lot simpler when these functions are indexed with a multi-index:
$$
\phi^\omega=\sum_{1\le i_1<\dots <i_{k-1}\le k}f_{i_1,\dots,i_{k-1}},dy_{i_1}\wedge \dots \wedge dy_{i_{k-1}},.
$$
The next expression must have something to do with $d\phi^*\omega$ which is easy to do in the multi-index format.

@KurtG. Thanks a lot. I will look into it.

Indeed, try to avoid working with differential forms by evaluating on sets of vectors. Here, let $$\phi^\omega = \sum (-1)^{i-1} f_i,dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{dx_i}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_k.$$  Then what is $d(\phi^\omega)$?  (My choice of $\pm$ coefficient will then become clear.) ... It would be more helpful if your post were more forthcoming with the complete context. It certainly is not clear to me why the author is doing this in such an awkward manner.

(If he's trying to prove that $d$ commutes with pullback, there are better ways that, again, avoid evaluating on vectors.)

@TedShifrin The author was indeed using very long calculations like these to prove that $d$ commutes with the pullback and also proving the generalized Stokes Theorem, but I was just wondering if I was missing something because I didn't understand how a lot of calculations worked. I've decided to use a different text to understand these things. Thanks for your help anyways!
